# Context API state is returning JSON unexpected error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I am following a tutorial guide built in NextJs using Context API to handle the state in the application but I keep getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` when I am on a shipping page from my store.js file where my reducer and state are defined.

I have done exactly what the tutorial guide has but it is still failing.

My shipping initial state.

```
const initialState = {

shippingAddress: Cookies.get("shippingAddress")
  ? JSON.parse(Cookies.get("shippingAddress"))
  : {},
```

My shipping.js file

```
const router = useRouter();
  // const { redirect } = router.query;
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Store);
  const { userInfo, cart: {shippingAddress} } = state;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userInfo) {
      router.push("/login?redirect=/shipping");
    }
    setValue('fullName', shippingAddress.fullName)
    setValue('address', shippingAddress.address)
    setValue('city', shippingAddress.city)
  }, []);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const submitHandler = ({ fullName, address, city}) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "SAVE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS",
      payload: { fullName, address, city},
    });
    Cookies.set("shippingAddress", {
      fullName,
      address,
      city,
    });
    router.push("/payment");
  };
```

What is the problem?
Github repo: https://github.com/suolomon/demo-store

Comment: Try like `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Cookies.get("shippingAddress")))`

Comment: Hey, thanks but my state is still not saved in the Context so I get ``` fullName``` in shipping address of undefined.